# Infinite Redirect Loop in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am trying to add redirect rule 'www' when the request comes without the 'www' for the site. ie. http://example.com to http://www.example.com

Here is what the rule looks like:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
            <rule name="Add www" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Once i add this rule, the site goes to infinite loop and it just error out (page can't be displayed error message). The server is brand new and it might be missing some redirect components (if there is one). I did install URL Rewrite component and added rule in it. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not chosen a pattern syntax and so you using the default regular expression syntax. As a result your pattern matches both example.com and www.example.com and causes an infinite loop. Try this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
            </conditions>
             <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: hmmm..didn't do anything. :(

Comment: I added the parameters,but this shouldn't change anything. Is there any other rule before that one? Do you have both bindinding in the site configuration and both entries in the DNS?